# Why does Javascript's array map callback require extra arguments

Tags: javascript, function, functional-programming

Say I have:

```
myArray = [1,2,3];
```

And say I have a util function somewhere else:

```
add3 = function(val) {
   return val+3;
}
```

Now if I want to use that as the call back for a map function, I have to do something like this:

```
add3Callback = function(currentValue, index, array) {
    return add3(currentValue);
}

myArray.map(add3Callback);
```

It would be better that the map callback doesn't require the extra two arguments, because now I have to add wrappers to all my util functions in order to use them with map, which goes against some of the reasons for using map in the first place.

What am I missing here? Why is having those arguments useful, other languages don't seem to do it.

Comment: It doesn't require any extra arguments, you can do `myArray.map(add3)`, same result.

Answer (score 6):

`map` provides these arguments for convenience, but they are not required, you'd get the same result with:

```
myArray.map(add3)
```

In case you have a function that can take more than one argument you can restrict it to a single argument:

```
myArray.map(unary(console.log))
```

where:

```
function unary(f) {
  return function(x) {
    return f(x)
  }
}
```

You can do this with `binary`, `ternary`, `nary`...

Note that no function in JS requires any arguments to be passed by name, doing:

```
function f(a, b, c) {
  return [a, b, c]
}
```

is the same as:

```
function f() {
  return [arguments[0], arguments[1], arguments[2]]
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Your callback function **is not required** to accept extra arguments. `map` will pass three arguments, but your function is entirely free to ignore them and not even list them in the parameter list.

This is perfectly valid:

```
myArray.map(function (currentValue) {
    return add3(currentValue);
});
```

And therefore so is this:

```
myArray.map(add3);
```

Answer (score 3):

You do not have to provide the extra parameters. In fact you do not have to provide any paramters at all. There is the [arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) object in JS, which has information of provided arguments for the function.

```
slice=Function.prototype.call.bind([].slice);
function fun(){
    slice(arguments).forEach(function(x){ console.log(x);})
}

fun(1,2,3,4);
```

Btw. `arguments` is one of those strange objects in JS: it behaves *arraylike* though not beeing an array. You could use `[]` to access elements, but e.g. no `forEach`.

So

```
function add3(){
    return arguments[0]+3;
}

console.log([1,2,3].map(add3))
```

is valid.

```
function add3(a,b,c,d){
    return a+3;
}
```

is valid too, though b,c,d are not needed.
If you put this into the map function

```
function add3(a,b,c,d){
    console.log(d)
    return a+3;
}
```

`d` is not used/called by `map()` and therefore `undefined`
You could say, that the parameters are optional or an "offer" to use, but there is no obligation to do so.

JS behaves in this regard a bit like [Perl](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/perl/perl_subroutines.htm).

Comment: Ah, I was just editing my question to include this info as well :P